# MySQL: cannot run source table_name.sql

Tags: mysql, database

I cannot run source table_name.sql
when I try, I get the following error:
ERROR: 
Failed to open file 'cars.sql', error: 2

I have been following zeetcode:
http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqltutorial/introduction/#mysql 
http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqltutorial/firststeps/

The first provides a list of commands to create a database called mydb and a set of tables to be used in the tutorial including one named Cars.

The second link shows you how to access the databases (SHOW DATABASES;) which I could do but when I go to the previously created database mydb, I can see the previously created tables including Cars (even though the tutorial says I should not see anything.

when I follow the next command: source cars.sql, I receive the error above
yet, this query works:
mysql> SELECT * FROM Cars;

any ideas as to why the source function would not work?

This is the first time I am working with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

where is the file cars.sql located? you may need to specify the full path to the file in order for it to be located by mysql.